# Are the two sentences synonymous?

Tags: synonyms

Are

> Method A is used in preference to Method B.

and

> Method A is used in favor of Method B.

synonymous (always)?  Which one is actually used in each case?

Comment: Neither flows well, the second not really making sense.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equivalent.

Neither makes much sense out of context, but the latter would more correctly be "Ordinary moments are disused in favor of central moments" -- "in favor of" generally indicates that the shift is toward what follows it, whereas you seem to be trying to say that the shift is toward central moments.

Whatever they are.